# LimeSurvey Rc2 api function export_responses() give error while exporting PDF

Tags: php, pdf, limesurvey

I am trying to export response in PDF format using export_responses(). This function works perfectly when I export response either in CSV or DOC format, but it always gives error in PDF.

```
require_once 'src/org/jsonrpcphp/jsonRPCClient.php';
// with composer support just add the autoloader
// include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

define( 'LS_BASEURL', 'http://localhost/limesurvey/');  // adjust this one to your actual LimeSurvey URL
define( 'LS_USER', 'admin' );
define( 'LS_PASSWORD', 'admin' );

// the survey to process
$survey_id=464658;

// instanciate a new client
$myJSONRPCClient = new org\jsonrpcphp\JsonRPCClient( LS_BASEURL.'/admin/remotecontrol' );

// receive session key
$sessionKey= $myJSONRPCClient->get_session_key( LS_USER, LS_PASSWORD );

$responses = $myJSONRPCClient->export_responses( $sessionKey, $survey_id, 'pdf', 'en','','','',11,11);
```

It always gives this error

[image: error]

Comment: Did you have a look at https://bugs.limesurvey.org ?